# How to plot 3D Bar chart/ Pie Chart/ Donut using Plotly

Tags: python, 3d, bar-chart, plotly, pie-chart

I have found code to make bar charts and pie charts in plotly also other 3D plots.
A simple bar chart works like this:

```
from  plotly.offline import plot
from plotly.graph_objs import *
trace1 = Bar(
    x=['cats', 'dogs', 'monkeys'],
    y=[20, 14, 23]
)
data = Data([trace1])
plot(data)
```

Is there any option available in plotly to plot this bar graph in 3D layout. Also for pie chart/donut also?

Comment: There is no real function in Plotly to do barchart3d and I was really disappointed by the look of 3D filled lines so I tried to create a function to create some nice looking easily. It's bind with a panda series but it's quite easy to convert a list to panda series. Here is the project : https://github.com/AymericFerreira/Plotly_barchart3D

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at the official documentation:
https://plot.ly/python/3d-charts/

As this should be a list of all available 3D Charts in plot.ly:

No, it seems there is currently no option for 3D Bar/Pie/Donut.

See also: https://community.plot.ly/t/will-there-be-3d-bar-charts-in-the-future/1045/2

Bar/Pie/Donut are two-dimensional by nature, making them 3D would provide no additional value (apart from cosmetics)

As suggested in the link above, you could try using [3D filled line plots](https://plot.ly/python/3d-filled-line-plots/).

Though I doubt that the additional complexity required to get the desired result is worth it.

Comment: should be a comment!

Comment: you are right - I thought the system would transform it automatically because of it's simple nature...

Comment: It wont, I think you need to give a more detailed explanation about plotly working, for this to qualify as an answer, now its only comment quality!

Comment: @SebastianLoehner already gone through that..i could find only specific graph layouts like scatter plot or other 3D graphs , but not for bar/pie/donut

Comment: @NarenMurali Thank you all for your feedback. I have updated the answer, so it will state explictly what was implicit before...

Comment: You don't know what is 3D bar. https://stackoverflow.com/a/63816226/3907561

Answer (score 1):

Still, 3D bar charts haven't been implemented in Plotly. There is a variant of 3D bar chart plotting function at https://github.com/buran21/barchart3d-plotly, intended for drawing of 1D labelled data. An example:

```
import plotly.data as pdata
from barchart3d import barchart3d

df = pdata.gapminder()
df = df[df['year'] == 2007].sort_values(by='pop', ascending=False).head(10)
fig = barchart3d(
    df['country'].to_list(), (df['pop']/1e06).round(1).to_list(),
    'Top 10 most populous countries in 2007 [Gapminder]', 'Population, mln',
    colorscale='Bluered', opacity=0.6, flatshading=True)
fig.show()
```

[image: Example output]